# react-router and express child routes not triggering

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, single-page-application

I'm trying to create a simple project configuration similar to jsfiddle but in my local machine.

I only want to have 3 files for each fiddle and a server to start the single page aplication. I mainly use the react ecosystem.

The problem comes when I want to use react-router. With this setup only the root '/' route triggers and all the children routes redirect to the index.html.

(I will omit the style file because I doubt its the source of the problem)

Any suggestions?

***server.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var morgan = require('morgan');
//var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var PORT = 3007;
var HOST = 'localhost'

var app = express();

/*
app.use(history({
  disableDotRule: true,
  verbose: true
}));
*/

app.use(morgan('tiny'));

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Always return the main index.html
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + HOST + ':' + PORT + '...');
});
```

***index.html***

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>multi-page-form-with-router</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.2.0/redux-thunk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.5.4/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.5.4/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.3/react-redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.4/ReactRouter.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-form/6.6.3/redux-form.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

***main.js***

```
const { Component } = React
const { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute, Link } = ReactRouter

const App = () => (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Header}>
      <IndexRoute component={Menu} />
      <Route path='first' component={FirstPage} />
      <Route path='second' component={SecondPage} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

const Header = () => (
  <h1>Multi-page form</h1>
)

const Menu = () => (
  <ul>
    <li><Link to='first'>Start form</Link></li>
  </ul>
)

const FirstPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>First Page</p>
      <Link to='second'>Next</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

const SecondPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Second Page</p>
      <Link to='overview'>Next</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

const Overview = () => {
  return (<p>Overview</p>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here, Root routes should render themselves but also render its childrens. In your example, Header is just rendering itsefl.

This is a working example I have:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={Root}>
    <Route path='/examples/react-redux-websocket' component={App} />
    <Route path='/examples/react-redux-websocket/chat/:chatid/participant/:participantid' component={Chat} />
    <Route path='/examples/react-redux-websocket/chat/:chatid' component={Chat} />
    <Route path='/*' component={NoMatch} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

**Root.js:**

```
class Root extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      //Render itself
      <div>
        //And its children too
        {this.props.children}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, all routes rendered inside the Root route will share same Footer. In your example, Header should render its children.

Now, If what you want is to have a hierarchy of urls, you need to specify each route. So If I want to have `/xxx/route_1` and `/xxx/route_2`, I need to specify them:

```
<Route path='/xxx/route_1' component={Route_1} />
<Route path='/xxx/route_2' component={Route_2} />
```

There might be some differences depending on the version you are using, for this example I am using react-route 3.0.2, but in general lines its usage is more or less the same.

I dont know what version are you using, but also you might need to reference route adding '/' before.

I hope to help you. Let me know if there is something you dont understand or you think is incorrect, we can discuss about.

You can take a look at the whole example [here](https://github.com/flarocca/react-redux-websocket), and you want to see it working you can find it [here](http://www.facundolarocca.com/examples/react-redux-websocket/)

Comment: Indded, I was missing the children. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect your `Link` tag to have a leading `slash(/)` like below

```
<Link to='/first'>Start form</Link>
```

Comment: I've tried both ways, neither one works. In fact, putting the path directly in the URL just triggers index.html. It does not matter which route you specify.